# How to fix incompatible architecture for gdal while running Django server in MacOs

Tags: python, django, macos

while running Django server by using `python manage.py runserver`, I'm getting following error.

Could anyone please help me to fix this issue.

```sh
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/usr/local/homebrew/opt/gdal/lib/libgdal.dylib, 0x0006): tried: '/usr/local/homebrew/opt/gdal/lib/libgdal.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/local/lib/libgdal.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libgdal.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/gdal/3.3.3_1/lib/libgdal.29.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/local/lib/libgdal.29.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libgdal.29.dylib' (no such file)
```

I am having M1 Chip MacBook Pro and I have installed the `gdal` in `/usr/local/homebrew/opt/gdal/`.